# Dynamically reading values from QTableWidget and store it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a `QTablewidget`, it can add rows and columns. Values can be inserted by user. I know how to get a single value of a cell by using `current.item()` method. But think and look at below image. User can insert different values and texts. I like to read a row values by its own. because I need to use values later. but I do not know how and where could values be read dynamically and still have a method to tell for exampel if a value under C is valid or not.

**Visualization:**

[image]

Here sees values at first row are, ***Text, 12, none, 25 and I***. User can add more rows and insert different values. I would like to have a method or a way to read and store all values of rows and at the same time one row at time.

I think a good solution could be with `QSortFilterProxyModel`. but how can values be read by this method?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def copy_widget(w):
    if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QWidget):
        new_w = type(w)()
        if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            vals = [w.itemText(ix) for ix in range(w.count())]
            new_w.addItems(vals)
        return new_w

class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 5, parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("A","B","C","D","E")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)

        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 4, combox_lay)

        self.cellChanged.connect(self._cellclicked)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def _cellclicked(self, r, c):
        it = self.item(r, c)
        it.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        n_it = self.item(r,1)
        n_it.setToolTip('Test') 


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _addrow(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowcount)
        combox_add = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_add.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(rowcount, 4, combox_add)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _removerow(self):
        if self.rowCount() > 0:
            self.removeRow(self.rowCount()-1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _copyrow(self):
        r = self.currentRow()
        if 0 <= r < self.rowCount():
            cells = {"items": [], "widgets": []}
            for i in range(self.columnCount()):
                it = self.item(r, i)
                if it:
                    cells["items"].append((i, it.clone()))
                w = self.cellWidget(r, i)
                if w:
                    cells["widgets"].append((i, copy_widget(w)))
            self.copy(cells, r+1)

    def copy(self, cells, r):
        self.insertRow(r)
        for i, it in cells["items"]:
            self.setItem(r, i, it)
        for i, w in cells["widgets"]:
            self.setCellWidget(r, i, w)   

class ThirdTabLoads(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThirdTabLoads, self).__init__(parent)    

        table = LoadTable()

        add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        add_button.clicked.connect(table._addrow)

        delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete")
        delete_button.clicked.connect(table._removerow)

        copy_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Copy")
        copy_button.clicked.connect(table._copyrow)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(add_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        button_layout.addWidget(delete_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        button_layout.addWidget(copy_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        tablehbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        tablehbox.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        tablehbox.addWidget(table)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(button_layout, 0, 1)
        grid.addLayout(tablehbox, 0, 0)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ThirdTabLoads()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out a way to read all values inserted by user. It is simple and uses `self.cellChanged.connect(self._row)` method. The only value I do not succeed to get is values of QcomboBox inside cells. it returns an empty string.

Here is the solution.

```
class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 5, parent)

        ------------------------

        self.cellChanged.connect(self._row)

        ------------------------

    def _row(self):
        row = self.rowCount()
        column = self.columnCount()
        A = []
        for r in range(row):
            for c in range(column):
                it = self.item(r,c)
                if it:
                    text = it.text()
                    A.append(text)
                    print( A, len(A))
```

Output as list with some random input:

```
['LC1', '-1200', '0', '', '', 'LC2', '', '', '20', ''] 10
```